# Best way to integrate ndarray into ros2

Tags: ros, python, ros2, publisher

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, I have a numpy ndarray, and when I try and publish it, I get this error:

`AssertionError: The 'data' field must be a set or sequence and each value of type 'float'`

Searching around, I see references to numpy in ros1, and also in the ros2 `ros2idl_generator_py`, however the only way I can seem to publish the array is to convert to a python list, which is *expensive*. Given that a numpy array is a sequence, is there any way to avoid this conversion?

Thank you for your time!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/398470/best-way-to-integrate-ndarray-into-ros2/) by [alluring-mushroom](https://answers.ros.org/users/97026/alluring-mushroom/) on ROS Answers with karma: 35 on 2022-04-03

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There have been some recent PRs on this topic that might give you some ideas:

- https://github.com/ros2/common_interfaces/pull/175
- https://github.com/ros2/geometry2/pull/507

---

Originally posted by [aprotyas](https://answers.ros.org/users/74476/aprotyas/) with karma: 456 on 2022-04-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [alluring-mushroom](https://answers.ros.org/users/97026/alluring-mushroom/) on 2022-05-05**:
Hey , thank you for your reply, and sorry for my late one! There is a bit to unpack with these, and we we are still bound to Foxy. I am unsure how much is back ported, but I will see what options I have here. Again, thank you :D

**Comment by [waspinator](https://answers.ros.org/users/4020/waspinator/) on 2022-09-10**:
did you end up finding a solution to publishing ndarrays without converting to a list?

**Comment by [alluring-mushroom](https://answers.ros.org/users/97026/alluring-mushroom/) on 2022-09-11**:
@waspinator,

Sorry, my work pulled me away from this particular path, so I have yet to actually dive into this properly.
Goodluck with your future pursuits!